# Did Cliff Clavin talk about Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, tv

John Ratzenberger famously played played insufferable would-be-know-it-all bar patron Cliff Clavin on the TV show "Cheers".

He also played Rebel Alliance officer [Bren Derlin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bren_Derlin) in The Empire Strikes Back. Given that Cheers aired mostly in the 80's and the waning height of Star Wars mania, it would make sense at some point for Cliff to have said something relating to Star Wars. Much like the TV show "Scrubs" janitor talking about a "dream" he had where he was a cop in the film "The Fugitive" (both played by actor Neil Flynn).

I doubt Cheers would have made such a meta reference, but did Cliff ever say *something* about Star Wars as a very subtle nod?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No.

Although *Cheers* featured a number of *Star Wars* references (such as when Woody decided, "You know, Darth Vader can't be Luke Skywalker's father. They don't have the same last name", and in episode titles such as "Bar Wars", "Bar Wars II: The Woodman Strikes Back" and "Bar Wars III: Return of Tecumseh"), the **character of Cliff himself never referenced *Star Wars* in any dialogue**.

I performed a search of episode scripts to be sure.